# How to trim JSON array to get specific value

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, sorting

So I am using the Echo Arena API Which gives me some of the following in JSON Format. I am trying to get all of the **NAMES** of users in the match at the time, as seen here there is player name: rnedds and further down DarkCobra866. How can I get just the names and none of the other information? Using Python 3.

```
{
   "teams":[
      {
         "players":[
            {
               "name":"rnedds",
               "rhand":[
                  -3.3230002,
                  -1.2370001,
                  -18.701
               ],
               "playerid":0,
               "position":[
                  -2.7520001,
                  -0.96800005,
                  -18.622002
               ],
               "lhand":[
                  -2.414,
                  -1.5630001,
                  -18.487001
               ],
               "userid":1663152230440088,
               "stats":{ }
            },
            {
               "name":"DarkCobra866",
               "rhand":[
                  -5.3710003,
                  -1.978,
                  -7.5110002
               ],
               "playerid":4,
               "position":[
                  -5.5280004,
                  -1.3520001,
                  -7.4040003
               ],
               "lhand":[
                  -5.6520004,
                  -1.7540001,
                  -7.4020004
               ],
               "userid":2649496045086049,
               "stats":{ }
            }
         ]
      }
   ]
}
```

Currently, my code looks like this for other information in the API

```
 matchdetails = {
    'echosessionid' : data['sessionid'],
    'echoclientname' : data['client_name'],
    'echogameclockdisplay' : data['game_clock_display'],
    'echogamestatus' : data['game_status']
    }
    currentMatchDetails = json.dumps(matchdetails)
```

Comment: please format the code and json properly

Comment: The json should pass via something like https://jsonlint.com/

Comment: consider that if there is info in the json you don't care about: why should we care about it? trimming it down will make the problem easier to solve.

Comment: Ok sorry, I am new to Programming and stackoverflow I hope that my edits are better.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Load your JSON string into a dictionary like this:

```py
import json

json_text = '''
{
   "teams":[
      {
         "players":[
            {
               "name":"rnedds",
               "rhand":[
                  -3.3230002,
                  -1.2370001,
                  -18.701
               ],
               "playerid":0,
               "position":[
                  -2.7520001,
                  -0.96800005,
                  -18.622002
               ],
               "lhand":[
                  -2.414,
                  -1.5630001,
                  -18.487001
               ],
               "userid":1663152230440088,
               "stats":{ }
            },
            {
               "name":"DarkCobra866",
               "rhand":[
                  -5.3710003,
                  -1.978,
                  -7.5110002
               ],
               "playerid":4,
               "position":[
                  -5.5280004,
                  -1.3520001,
                  -7.4040003
               ],
               "lhand":[
                  -5.6520004,
                  -1.7540001,
                  -7.4020004
               ],
               "userid":2649496045086049,
               "stats":{ }
            }
         ]
      }
   ]
}
'''

data = json.loads(json_text)

players = [player['name'] for team in data['teams'] for player in team['players']]

print(players)
```

The above code will result in:

```py
['rnedds', 'DarkCobra866']
```